# Idris vectors vs linked lists

Tags: vector, linked-list, algebraic-data-types, idris

Does Idris do any kind of optimization under the hood of vectors? Because from the looks of it, an Idris vector is just a linked list with known size (known at compile time). In fact, in general it seems like you could express the following equivalence (I'm guessing a bit at the syntax):

```
Vector : Nat -> Type -> Type
Vector n t = (l: List t ** length l = n)
```

So while this is nice in the sense of preventing range errors, the real advantage of vectors (in the traditional usage of the term) is in terms of performance; in particular, O(1) random access. It seems that the idris vector would not support this (how would you write the indexing function to have this performance?).

- Assuming that there's no wizardry going on under the hood (as happens with `Nat`) to reconfigure `Vector`s, is there a random-access data type in Idris?
- How would be/is such a thing defined in an algebraic type system? Certainly it *seems* like it would be impossible to define it inductively.
- Is it possible, within a type system like that of Idris, to create a data type which supports O(1) random access, *and* is aware of its length such that all access is provably valid? (Haskell has array-style Vectors, but their concrete implementation is opaque to the average user, including me)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It doesn't do anything to optimise Vector lookups (at the time of writing this answer, at least).

This isn't because of any difficulty in doing it, really, but more because I would rather have some kind of general framework for writing this kind of optimisation than hard coding lots of them. Admittedly, we already have hard coded optimisations for `Nat`, but I still would prefer not to add loads more in an ad-hoc fashion.

Depending on what you actually want it for, it might be that the experimental uniqueness type system will help, in that you could have a low level mutable thing under the hood and still have safe and efficient access and update in a pure style in the high level language. We'll see...

Answer (score 3):

[Edwin has the definitive answers on what Idris currently does.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27636012/377022)  However, if you are looking for something which might be natural to optimize into constant-time lookup in some cases, the following might be a step in the right direction.

For compile-time fixed-size vectors (i.e., not under a lambda, not parameterized by length at top-level), the following structure gives you vectors and lookup functions that, for any fixed concrete length, can be compile-time normalized to functions that should be somewhat straightforwardly optimizable into constant-time functions.  (Sorry, code is in Coq; I don't have a working version of Idris at the moment, and don't know it well.  I'm happy to replace this with Idris code if someone suggests the right syntax, e.g., in a comment.)

```
Fixpoint vector (n : nat) (A : Type) :=
  match n return Type with
    | 0 => unit
    | S n' => (A * vector n' A)%type
  end.
Definition nil {A} : vector 0 A := tt.
Definition cons {n} {A : Prop} (x : A) (xs : vector n A) : vector (S n) A
  := (x, xs).
Fixpoint get {n} {A : Prop} (m : nat) (default : A) (v : vector n A) {struct n} : A
  := match n as n return vector n A -> A with
       | 0 => fun _ => default
       | S n' => match m with
                   | 0 => fun v => fst v
                   | S m' => fun v => @get n' A m' default (snd v)
                 end
     end v.
```

The idea is that, for any fixed *n*, the normal form of `get` is non-recursive, so the compiler could, hypothetically, compile it into a function whose runtime is independent of what *n* happens to be.

Comment: The original question was about accessing an element in O(1).  Obviously, if you fix *n*, then the access is going to be in constant time.

Comment: I've edited the last sentence to make the following point clearer, I hope: The point is that *n* must be fixed to a value wherever it is used.  It should be O(1) as a function of the value that you fix *n* to at compile time.  That is, in a hypothetical world where Idris can compile `A * B * ... * C` into an array, the absolute run time when you plug in *n* = 5 should be the same as when you plug in *n* = 100000, but only if you do it at compile-time.